# Creating a list with inputs prompted by the user?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm a beginner and taking an intro Python course. The first part of my lab assignment asks me to create a list with numbers entered by the user. I'm a little confused. I read some other posts here that suggest using "a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]" but I'm not sure how to use it or why, for that matter. The code I wrote before based on the things I've read in my textbook is the following:

```
 while True: 
  num = int(input('Input a score (-99 terminates): ')) 
   if num == -99: 
   break
```

Here's the problem from the professor:

> Your first task here is to input score values to a list called scores and you
>   will do this with a while loop. That is, prompt user to enter value for scores
>   (integers) and keep on doing this until user enters the value of -99.
>   Each time you enter a value you will add the score entered to list scores. The
>   terminating value of -99 is not added to the list
>   Hence the list scores should be initialized as an empty list first using the
>   statement:
>   scores = []
>   Once you finish enter the values for the list, define and called a find called
>   print_scores() that will accept the list and then print each value in the list in
>   one line separate by space.
>   You should use a for-loop to print the values of the list.

Comment: Here is a hint to get you going. When you get your input, you want to do something like `scores.append(num)`. That will start collecting your numbers in to the `scores` list. Try to play around with that in your code.

Comment: You pretty much have what the first part of the assignment asks for. You just need to create a list to store each value the user enters.

Comment: Create a `mylist = []` before the loop and do `mylist.append(num)` each time you receive a new `num`

Comment: You are one line away from success as described above :)

Comment: Just to complement what @idjaw already said, here's another hint: Make sure to define `scores` _outside_ of the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yeah, you want to continually loop a scan, asking for input, and check the input every time. If it's -99, then break. If its not, append it to the list. Then pass that to the print function

```
def print_list(l):
    for num in l:
        print(num, ' ', end='')
l = []
while True:
    s = scan("enter some number (-99 to quit)")
    if s == "-99":
        break
    l.append(int(s))

print_list(l)
```

the     print(num, ' ', end='')  is saying "print num, a space, and not a newline"

Comment: Thank you for your help :) @mauricio

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the job:

```
def print_scores(scores):
 for score in scores:
  print(str(score), end = " ")
 print("\n")

scores = []
while True:
 num = int(input('Input a score (-99 terminates)'))
 if num == -99:
  break
 scores.append(num)
print_scores(scores)
```

`scores = []` creates an empty array and `scores.append()` adds the element to the list.

`print()` will take `end = ' '` so that it separates each result with a space instead of a newline (`\n'`) all while conforming to the requirement to use a loop `for` in the assignment. `str(score)` ensures the integer is seen as a string, but it's superfluous here.

This is actually not an elegant way to print the scores, but the teacher probably wanted to not rush things.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This makes more sense now. :)